# mysql_config_editor with docker

Tags: mysql, bash, docker, dockerfile

Hi I'm trying to use mysql_config_editor tools directly in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql
RUN mysql_config_editor set --login-path=local --user=root --password
```

But this command ask the user to enter the password. Is there a way to set the password directly from the Dockerfile knowing that it is not possible to set the password directly in the command line.

```
root@d80484a3177f:~# mysql_config_editor set --login-path=local --user=root --password                   
Enter password: 

root@d80484a3177f:~# mysql_config_editor set --login-path=local --user=root --password=root
mysql_config_editor: [ERROR] mysql_config_editor: option '--password' cannot take an argument
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `expect` to do this :

This is your Dockerfile :

```
FROM mysql:5.7

RUN apt-get update && apt-get --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y install expect

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD "secure_root_password"

ADD mysql_config.sh /root/mysql_config.sh
RUN cd /root && ./mysql_config.sh $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

And this is mysql_config.sh :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set pwd [lindex $argv 0];

spawn mysql_config_editor set --login-path=local --host=localhost --user=root --password
expect -nocase "Enter password:" {send "${pwd}\r"; interact}
```

Now you can connect directly to MySQL :

```
$ docker exec -it your-mysql-container mysql --login-path=local
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 6
Server version: 5.7.18 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Maybe it's not the cleanest way, but it works !